# What happened to Voldemort's body after he died the first time?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort

Towards the end of the film adaption of Harry Pitter and The Deathly Hallows pt 2, we see that Voldemort disintegrates after losing his duel with Harry. However, in the books, Voldemort's body is left behind, and is "left apart from the bodies of those who fell in the battle."

On the night that Voldemort murdered Harry's parents, he would also, presumably, have left a body behind. What happened to it? In The Goblet of Fire, Voldemort needs Wormtail to make him a new one using dark magic, so was it cremated or buried by the ministry of magic?

Comment: @fez cheers. I'd searched "after he died" and didn't get any results, forgot to search for things about his body

Comment: You search for whole sentences? That can needlessly restrict the results. Better search only for keywords (like "Voldemort body") and try a few different things.